# Using jQuery and Ajax to Change an Element's Style for All Users

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I'd like to have a button that changes the display property of a certain element for all users of a site, not just the person who clicked the button. The button is used to show that a user is online by changing an element's display from "none" to "inline" and should be visible to all. So far I have an html file with the button that changes the display property with jQuery:

```
<div id="john" style="display:none">John</div>

<script>
var goOnline = function (user) {
    $('#' + user).css('display', 'inline');
}

</script>


<button type="button" onclick="goOnline(john);"/>Go Online</button>
```

I've looked around and using jQuery's Ajax functionality seems to be a good solution but I'm not sure how to implement it properly. I'd really appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need something on the server side where your Ajax call can store the current display property and which gets polled from time to time by another Ajax call. If you don't know how to do that on your own maybe check out the **Meteor** framework at http://meteor.com/ which does exactly what you want to do.

Comment: You could try adding an interval on which to reload the css file for every client. And to make the change you would have to overwrite the file. It would waste a lot of resources though with each visitor sending a request every 2-5 seconds to see if the file has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes on the server for that. And I'm not sure what would be the best approach for making all other clients update immediately. That could involve, for instance, [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29)

If you are planing on having similar functionality with other things too (i.e. other things one user can change for everyone), I would recommend you to use a database to store those values and check them on each render of a site. With this, the changes will not become immediately available to all users, but when there is a page refresh (or an ajax call), changes will be reflected.

Comment: Ok, I'll try using a database to store values because I don't necessarily need the changes to be seen by everyone immediately. Thanks.